# How to Install Oracle 12 on Debian Jessie server?

Tags: debian, software-installation, oracle-database

I want to install Oracle version 12 on a server Debian Jessie, but I can't find any tutorial or commands to follow.

How can I install it?

Comment: I don't know if that's important for you but I don't think that Debian is officially supported (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/pre_install.htm#LADBI7533)

Comment: thanks but at work i have a Debian Jessie server so i don't have a choice

Comment: Without an officially supported OS you need a great deal of luck. If you would use CentOS the chances are much higher but I can't imagine that it#s working with with Debian...